# Python Web-based Bot

Tags: python, html, bots

I am trying to write a Python-based Web Bot that can read and interpret an HTML page, then execute an onClick function and receive the resulting new HTML page. I can already read the HTML page and I can determine the functions to be called by the onClick command, but I have no idea how to execute those functions or how to receive the resulting HTML code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only tool in Python for Javascript, that I am aware of is [python-spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/). I have never used it though.

With Jython you could (ab-)use [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/index.html).

**Edit**: forgot that you can use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It supports Javascript through Spidermonkey, and you can even use Firefox for crawling the web.

**Edit 2**: Recently, I find myself using browser automation more and more for such tasks thanks to some excellent libraries. [QtWebKit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-module.html) offers full access to a WebKit browser, which can be used in Python thanks to language bindings ([PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) or [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)). There seem to be similar libraries and bindings for Gtk+ which I haven't tried. [Selenium WebDriver API](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) also works great and has an active community.

Comment: upvoted for mentioning scrapy. Wasn't aware of that. Looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Well obviously python won't interpret the JS for you (though there may be modules out there that can). I suppose you need to convert the JS instructions to equivalent transformations in Python.

I suppose ElementTree or BeautifulSoup would be good starting points to interpret the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

To execute JavaScript, you need to do much of what a full web browser does, except for the rendering. In particular, you need a JavaScript interpreter, in addition to the Python interpreter.

One starting point might be [python-spidermonkey](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey). Depending on the specific JavaScript, you might have to provide a good DOM API to the spidermonkey, in addition to providing an XmlHttpRequest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to leverage [V8](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/intro.html),

> V8 is Google's open source, high performance JavaScript engine. It is written in C++ and is used in Google Chrome, Google's open source browser.

Calling it from `Python` may not be straightforward, without a framework to provide the DOM.
[`Pyjamas`](http://pyjs.org/) has an experimental project, [*Pyjamas Desktop*](http://pyjd.org/), providing `V8` integration for `Javascript` execution.

[`Pyv8`](http://advogato.org/article/985.html) is an experimental python v8 bindings and a python-javascript compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For the browser part of this you might want to look into Mechanize, which basically is a webbrowser implemented as a Python library. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.1.11
But as mentioned, the text n onClick is Javascript, and you'll need spidermonkey for that.

If you can make a generic support for spidermonkey in mechanize, I'm sure many people would be extremely happy. ;)

Mechanize may be overkill, maybe you just want to find specific parts of the HTML, and then lxml and BeautifulSoup both work well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just sniff what gets sent after the onclick event and replicate that with your bot?

Answer (score 0):

> For web automation , you can look into "**webbot**" library. It makes autmation damn simple and pain free.

webbot works even for webpages with dynamically changing id and classnames and has more methods and features than selenium and mechanize.

Here's a snippet of webbot

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId') # specific selection
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^
```

Docs are at : https://webbot.readthedocs.io